# Installing SMTP module, not able to enable module

Tags: 8

On a Drupal site that I've inherited, I'm trying to fix an issue where the contact form isn't sending out emails. To that end, I'm attempting to install, enable, and configure the SMTP module to see if that will fix things.

I've attempted to install the SMTP module via direct link as well as uploading it myself. While the module appears in the site admin list, I'm not able to enable it (just goes to a yellow "on", and then back to disabled).

What are some ways to figure out what the conflict or problem may be?

Comment: Try to use 'drush en module_id' to enable it. It will give you an error if something is wrong.

Comment: Just made a SSH connection - appears that drush is not installed. This is hosted on Dreamhost, and the SSH user that I'm using isn't in SUDO group, so I'm not sure that I'll be able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your host provider does not have one or more of the PhP extensions enabled for your site.  Check the status page / php info to see if the following items listed in the readme are there:

> ### REQUIREMENTS
>
> - Access to an SMTP server
> - The following PHP extensions need to be installed: ereg, hash, date & pcre.
> - Optional: To connect to an SMTP server using SSL, you need to have the   openssl package installed on your server, and your webserver and
>     PHP   installation need to have additional components installed and
>     configured.

If the requirements are there, check the watchdog error log (you probably have).

If possible, check the actual server error logs.

If you can't check the error logs, you might try going to the Logging and Error settings in the Devel area and setting the option to display all errors with a stacklog.

NOTE: This should be reset once your debugging is done.